# how to code different type of border in css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

how to code different type of border in css ?
I want to design a group of border styles in my html template . sometimes I am confused should I add some border css code under a special css seletor such as .hello , or should I seperate the border styles to a border css group. I am using sass+bootstrap now. I want css export give me some principle to do the job.

```
<div class="box bodered">has border around box</div>
<div class="box bodered dotted">border type is dotted</div>
<div class="box bodered type_1">border type with image shadow effort</div>

<div class="box bordered top">only has border at top</div>
<div class="box bordered left">only has border at left</div>
<div class="box bordered right">only has border at right</div>
<div class="box bordered bottom">only has border at bottom</div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure you need the `bordered` class at all, as each variation will need to specify most of the border attributes anyway.

Comment: That's a lot of presentation in your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       .box{ border-color:#000000;}
       .bodered{ border:1px solid inherit;}
       .dotted{ border-style:dotted;}
       .top{border:none; border-top:1px solid #00000;}
       .left{border:none;border-left:1px solid #00000;}
       .right{border:none;border-right:1px solid #00000;}
       .bottom{border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #00000;}
```